# How to specify the timeout for serverless pool in Azure DevOps deployment job strategy step

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a deployment job which runs on a self hosted agent, using the runOnce strategy. In the postRouteTraffic I want to use the ManualValidation@0 task, but that must run on an agentless server. But that does not respect thet timeoutInMinutes set on the top level and is just the default of 60 min. You can specify a separate pool at each strategy step, but can't set the timeoutInMinutes, that seems to me as an omission.

```
jobs:
- deployment: DeployCloud
  displayName: Deploy cloud
  pool: MyPoolSelfHosted
  workspace:
    clean: all
  environment: TestCloud
  timeoutInMinutes: 12960 # 9 days
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
          ...
      routeTraffic:
        steps:
          ...
      postRouteTraffic:
        pool: server
        steps:
          - task: ManualValidation@0
            timeoutInMinutes: 11520 # 8 days
            inputs:
              notifyUsers: 'someone@domain.com' 
              instructions: '..........' 
              onTimeout: 'reject'
      on:
        success:
          steps:
            ...
```

With above setup, the postRouteTraffic job just timeouts after the default 60 minutes.
How to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, we cannot set `timeoutInMinutes` for each deployment lifecycle hook, no matter it is an agent or agentless job. Thus, the default 60-minute timeout for agentless jobs has limited the job execution time.

Still, I can't agree more that this limiation is not a good design. For this, you may consider creating a feature request via [Developer Community (visualstudio.com)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion). That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate Product Group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.

Hope the information helps.

Comment: I assume this is still the case? We have an environment agent running in docker that needs to execute a test job which takes 2 hours, worked fine with old classic pipelines yet no matter where `timeoutInMinutes: 360` is added it always caps at 60

Answer (score 0):

Try to define `timeoutInMinutes` on the deployment level: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-deployment?view=azure-pipelines

Update this:

```
  postRouteTraffic:
    pool: server
    steps:
      - task: ManualValidation@0
        timeoutInMinutes: 11520 # 8 days
```

to:

```
  postRouteTraffic:
    pool: server
    timeoutInMinutes: 11520 # 8 days
    steps:
      - task: ManualValidation@0
```

The same was reported here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-devops-timeoutinminutes-is-being-ignored-in/567714